# How can I sort a list of images by the number of matching tags?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a query to sort images based on tags. The data is organised like this:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ImageTag> Tags { get; }
    // Some more properties
}

public class ImageTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

The controller method receives a comma separated string called `csvTags`, which could be something like "flower,plant,daffodil".

The expected result would be a list where images containing all three words as tag would be at the top, and then descending downwards in number of matching tags.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Transfer the CSV-data into a List<string>:
List<string> tagsList = csvTags.Split(",").ToList();

// Get those tags from the db, and include the related image of each tag.
// Since a tag can be present on multiple images, this list will likely contain several
// instances of each tag.
List<ImageTag> tags = await db.ImageTags
    .Include(i => i.Image)
    .Where(t => tagsList.Contains(t.Tag))
    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

// Use the list of tags to make a list of images:
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
foreach (ImageTag tag in tags)
{
    // Need some magic here...
    // Sort the list by count of tags, and .Distinct() it.
    images.Add(tag.Image);
}
```

Actually, if it's at all possible, I would like to avoid that `foreach`-part.

**UPDATE**

I accepted Tieson's answer, but a bit too soon, without testing it. It turns out, it doesn't work after all. I get this error message:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>   .Where(w0 => EF.Property>((EntityShaperExpression:
>   EntityType: WebContentsImage
>   ValueBufferExpression:
>   (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>   IsNullable: False
>   ), "Id") != null && EF.Property>((EntityShaperExpression:
>   EntityType: WebContentsImage
>   ValueBufferExpression:
>   (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>   IsNullable: False
>   ), "Id") == EF.Property>(w0, "ImageId"))
>   .Count(w0 => __csvTags_0.Contains(
>   value: w0.Tag,
>   comparisonType: CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The query can't be translated into an SQL query because of this line:

```
Matches = m.Tags.Count(n => tagsList.Contains(n.Tag))
```

How can I rewrite it?

**UPDATE 2**

Running the new query on an in-memory collection works:

```
List<WebContentsImage> unsortedImages = 
    await db.WebContentsImages.Include(t => t.Tags).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

List<WebContentsImage> images = unsortedImages
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Image = m,
        Matches = m.Tags.Count(n => csvTags.Contains(n.Tag, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    })
    .Where(m => m.Matches > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Matches)
    .Select(m => m.Image)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to verify without building a similar database to query against, but something like this should work:

```cs
var result = db.Images
    .Include(m => m.Tags)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Image = m,
        Matches = m.Tags.Count(n => tagsList.Any(o => o == n.Tag))
    })
    .Where(m => m.Matches > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Matches)
    .Select(m => m.Image)
    .ToList();
```

That should get you a list of Image objects, sorted by the number of associated tags which match any of the search terms. If you wanted the number of matches, leave out the last Select():

```cs
var result = db.Images
    .Include(m => m.Tags)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Image = m,
        Matches = m.Tags.Count(n => tagsList.Any(o => o == n.Tag))
    })
    .Where(m => m.Matches > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Matches)
    .ToList();
```

This would return an anonymous/dynamic object with an Image property and a Matches property.

Comment: How would I define the viewmodel in the .cshtml-file?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to bind. If all you need is the list of images, your model declaration is something like `@model List<Image>`, or `@model List<dynamic>` if you want to use my second example. You lose Intellisense on the latter, since there's no defined properties on `dynamic`.

Comment: I had to migrate from Asp.Net Core 2.2 to 3.0 to make your query work. I had intended to do it anyway, but had been putting it off for a while. Thanks for the push! :)

Comment: Can you check out the update to my question? I accepted your answer without testing it, and it doesn't work after all The above comment about migrating to 3.0 was about not getting an compile time error. At runtime, I get the exception described in the updated question. Sorry.

Comment: I image it's the Contains call - there's no translation for that in LINQ-to-Entities (it _would_ work if it was run against an in-memory collection). I can suggest an edit, but I don't have a good way of testing it, lacking your database.

Comment: The problem with going that route is that you're selecting a lot of records and then throwing them away. Not a big deal with small datasets, but it will be after a while.